# C-g isn't aborting isearch and returning to intial position

Tags: emacs

After using <kbd>C-s</kbd><kbd>C-w</kbd> or <kbd>C-s</kbd> to search I can't abort the search with <kbd>C-g</kbd>. Although I see the *Quit* message in the mini-buffer yet the point/cursor doesn't go back to it's initial position nor is the `isearch` quitting.

I tried testing this in `emacs -q` and then `eval`ed my entire `init.el` piece by piece, but it didn't affect `isearch`'s functionality.

Even tried `eval`ing the entire `isearch.el` but that too didn't fix the issue.

How can I fix this issue?

*Emacs version: GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7600) of 2013-03-18 on MARVIN*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have no clue as to what could have gone wrong, but a simple Emacs restart solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

State your Emacs build: do at least `M-x emacs-version`.  If it is a development snapshot from the last month or so, then know that there was a period where certain control chars did not exit Isearch.  If that is your case, then upgrade to a more recent snapshot (the regression was fixed).

If that does not apply to your case, then (since you say that your init file has no bearing on the problem), try to give a clear, step by step recipe, starting from `emacs -Q`.  If things are actually as you describe them, then this would be an Emacs bug.  If you think that is the case, then use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to provide your recipe to Emacs Dev.

Comment: The thing is I restarted Emacs and the problem's no more there. Emacs version added.

Comment: Thx for the update. It's good to let people know that, so they don't waste time trying to figure out the problem.  You can even post your own "rebooted" answer as an answer, and accept it if it is the best answer.  That way, the question is closed and people won't bother with it.